# Script to compare data in one column against one row and write to corresponding column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

The first part of my script is working fine as they are basic commands. The first clears the data present so it is ready to be re-written. The second sorts the data by region and start date. I am stuck on the 3rd part.

I have a set of dates in column C with a subject line in column E. I have corresponding dates in row 1 Columns L through NL. I am trying to write a script that will take the date of each row, compare it to the columns L:NL and if there is a match it will paste the subject in the corresponding cell.

I know there is something wrong with either my `for` statement or my `if` statement because right now it writes the subject of each row in column L only.

Here is an example [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OFMKvGsi7Omn1PL5XFR1RLiCo1Z3fFDTATJzziMlJts/edit#gid=0/).

```
function clear_Sort_Label() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  //Clear current data before resort and write
  var rangesToClear = sheet.getRange("L3:NL");
  rangesToClear.clearContent();

  //Sort the data by region then start date
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:K");
  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 3, ascending: true}]);

  //Compare Start date (Column C) against dates in Row 1 Columns L:NL
  //Each match paste value from subject (Column E) in coresponding cell
  var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows()
  var lastCol = sheet.getMaxColumns() 
  for (var i=3; i<lastRow; i++) {
    var meetingSubject = sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
    var startDay = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();  
    Logger.log(startDay)
    var day = sheet.getRange(1,12,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
    if(startDay = day){
      sheet.getRange(i,12).setValue(meetingSubject);
  }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to correspond the dates of column "C" and column "D" to the dates of "L1:NL1" as the range.
- You want to put the value of column "E" to the first cell of the corresponded range.
- You want to change the background color of the corresponded range to `#b7e1cd`.

If my understanding of your question is correct, how about this modification? From your question, I could understand that both the scripts of "Clear current data before resort and write" and "Sort the data by region then start date" work fine. So I modified about "the 3rd part". I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Flow:

The flow of this modification is as follows.

1. Retrieve values of "C3:E".
2. Retrieve dates of "L1:NL1".
3. Compare each row of the values of "C3:E" to dates of "L1:NL1", and create an array for using at the output.
4. Create 2 new arrays for putting to the cells "L3:NL". Those are used for values and background colors.
5. Put values to 2 new arrays using the array created at section 3.
6. Put the values and set the background colors.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var lastRow = sheet.getMaxRows()
var lastCol = sheet.getMaxColumns() 
for (var i=3; i<lastRow; i++) {
  var meetingSubject = sheet.getRange(i,5).getValue();
  var startDay = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();  
  Logger.log(startDay)
  var day = sheet.getRange(1,12,1,lastCol).getValues()[0];
  if(startDay = day){
    sheet.getRange(i,12).setValue(meetingSubject);
}
```

To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("C3:E").getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f){return f})}).map(function(e) {return [e[0].getTime(), e[1].getTime(), e[2]]});
var dates = sheet.getRange("L1:NL1").getValues()[0].map(function(e) {return e.getTime()});
var res = values.reduce(function(ar1, e, i) {
  var r = dates.reduce(function(ar2, f, j) {
    if (f == e[0]) ar2.push([e[2], i, j]);
    if (f == e[1]) ar2.push(j);
    return ar2;
  }, []);
  if (r.length == 2) ar1.push(Array.prototype.concat.apply([], r));
  return ar1;
}, []);
var row = values.length;
var col = dates.length;
var values = Array.apply(null, Array(row)).map(function() {return Array.apply(null, Array(col)).map(function() {return ""})});
var colors = Array.apply(null, Array(row)).map(function() {return Array.apply(null, Array(col)).map(function() {return ""})});
res.forEach(function(e) {
  values[e[1]][e[2]] = e[0];
  for (var i = e[2]; i <= e[3]; i++) {
    colors[e[1]][i] = "#b7e1cd";
  }
});
sheet.getRange("L3:NL" + (row + 2)).setValues(values).setBackgrounds(colors);
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to change the background colors, please remove `.setBackgrounds(colors)` from `sheet.getRange("L3:NL" + (row + 2)).setValues(values).setBackgrounds(colors)`.

#### References:

- [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
- [setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

### Added:

If you want to use the sample spreadsheet including the internal headers, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("C3:E").getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f){return f})}).map(function(e) {return [e[0].getTime(), e[1].getTime(), e[2]]});
var dates = sheet.getRange("L1:NL1").getValues()[0].map(function(e) {return e.getTime()});
var res = values.reduce(function(ar1, e, i) {
  var r = dates.reduce(function(ar2, f, j) {
    if (f == e[0]) ar2.push([e[2], i, j]);
    if (f == e[1]) ar2.push(j);
```

#### To:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A3:E").getValues().filter(function(e) {return e.some(function(f){return f})}).map(function(e) {return [e[0], e[2].getTime(), e[3].getTime(), e[4]]});
var dates = sheet.getRange("L1:NL1").getValues()[0].map(function(e) {return e.getTime()});
var res = values.reduce(function(ar1, e, i) {
  var r = dates.reduce(function(ar2, f, j) {
    if (e[0] && f == e[1]) ar2.push([e[3], i, j]);
    if (e[0] && f == e[2]) ar2.push(j);
```

Comment: You are brilliant!! Thank you so so so much!!! This is exactly what I needed. The coloring of cells is more complex as it will be different colors based on the category selected in Column F. For now I can use conditional formatting but will be switching it to a script later. Any advice you can give now be appreciated.

Comment: @Leilani I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Comment: @tanaika - I did not realize that my headers for each section would be a problem for the script. Is there any way to update the script to ignore them? I have updated the spreadsheet with the test data for reference.

Comment: @Leilani About ``I did not realize that my headers for each section would be a problem for the script.``, you want to use the sample spreadsheet including the internal headers. I understand like this. If my understanding is correct, please modify like the added script. But I'm not sure about the specification you are thinking. So if I misunderstand about your new issue, can you post the question including what you want as a new question? I'm really sorry for my poor skill.